# Welche Benennungsschemata für die verschiedenen Konjunktivformen gibt es und wie funktionieren sie?

Tags: subjunctive, terminology

Offensichtlich gibt es verschiedene Benennungsschemata für die deutschen Konjunktivformen. Zum Beispiel wird *ich wäre* manchmal als *Konjunktiv Präteritum* und manchmal als *Konjunktiv II* bezeichnet.

Welche derartigen Schemata gibt es und wie funktionieren sie?

Dabei geht es mir explizit nicht darum, welches Schema besser ist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es gibt zwei wesentliche Schemata.

Das erste, ältere Schema benennt die Konjunktiv-Formen nach der Form, von der sie abgeleitet sind, z. B. ist *er gehe* aus dem Präsensstamm von *gehen* abgeleitet und wird daher als *Konjunktiv Präsens* bezeichnet; *ich wäre* ist aus den Präteritumsformen (z. B. *ich war)* abgeleitet und wird daher als *Konjunktiv Präteritum* bezeichnet.

Das zweite, neuere Schema orientiert sich an den Verwendungszwecken. *Konjunktiv I* bezeichnet die Form, die bevorzugt und überwiegend für indirekte Rede genutzt wird. *Konjunktiv II* bezeichnet die Form, die bevorzugt und überwiegend für den Irrealis genutzt wird. Wird über die Vergangenheit oder Zukunft gesprochen, wird dies durch einen entsprechenden Zusatz gekennzeichnet.

Daraus ergibt sich dann, mit den Beispielen *ich bin* und *er macht (Konjunktiv* abgekürzt mit *K.):*

| Beispiel 1 | Beispiel 2 | altes Schema | neues Schema |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *ich sei* | *er mache* | K. Präsens | K. I |
| *ich wäre* | *er machte* | K. Präteritum | K. II |
| *ich sei gewesen* | *er habe gemacht* | K. Perfekt | K. I der Vergangenheit¹ |
| *ich wäre gewesen* | *er hätte gemacht* | K. Plusquamperfekt | K. II der Vergangenheit¹ |
| *ich werde sein* | *er werde machen* | K. Futur | K. I Futur |
| *ich würde sein* | *er würde machen* | —²³ | K. II Futur³ |
| *ich werde gewesen sein* | *er werde gemacht haben* | K. Futur II | K. I Futur II |
| *ich würde gewesen sein* | *er würde gemacht haben* | —² | K. II Futur II |

<sub>¹ Manchmal auch bezeichnet als *Konjunktiv I Perfekt* bzw. *Konjunktiv II Perfekt.*

² Passt nicht in dieses Schema, da *ich wurde sein* bzw. *ich wurde gewesen sein* keine existierenden Verbformen sind.

³ Auch bezeichnet als *würde-Form,* insbesondere wenn als Ersatzform für den Konjunktiv II genutzt.</sub>

Schließlich gibt es noch eine Mischung der beiden Schemata, die weitestgehend dem alten Schema folgt, aber zusätzlich die Nummern I und II nutzt, also z. B. *Konjuktiv II Plusquamperfekt* statt *Konjunktiv Plusquamperfekt.*